# UserControl's constructor

Tags: c#, wpf

I have my own WPF UserControl (e.g. Image + ViewBox - it does not matter). This control has boolean Dependency property, e.g. NeedToDrawRect. What I want to achieve: when user sets (in XAML) this property to true, I need to perform some action - but only once. 
I've planned to perform this action in c-tor, but it seems that I can not see this property value on that stage yet:

XAML:

```
<pzi:PanZoomImage Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" NeedToDrawRect="True" />
```

UserControl constructor:

```
public PanZoomImage()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LayoutRoot.DataContext = this;

    // Here NeedToDrawRect is still false
    if (NeedToDrawRect)
           DoSmth();            
}
```

So, where can I check value that user set in XAML. Of course I can override OnRender and check there every time, but I'd like to use the *right* way to do this.

Comment: Either in a Loaded event handler, or in a PropertyChangedCallback that is registered with dependency property metadata in DependencyProperty.Register. Where the latter is the "right way", IMO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Register a `PropertyChangedCallback` for the dependency property:

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty NeedToDrawRectProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(nameof(NeedToDrawRect),
    typeof(bool), typeof(PanZoomImage ), new PropertyMetadata(new PropertyChangedCallback(OnValueChanged)));

public bool NeedToDrawRect
{
    get { return (bool)GetValue(NeedToDrawRectProperty); }
    set { SetValue(NeedToDrawRectProperty, value); }
}

private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    var ctrl = (PanZoomImage)d;
    var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
    //...
}
```

The callback will be invoked whenever the dependency property is set to a new value.

If you only want to do something once, you could use a private field to keep track of whether the callback has been invoked before, e.g.:

```
private int n;

private static void OnValueChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (n++ > 0)
    {
        var ctrl = (PanZoomImage)d;
        var newValue = (bool)e.NewValue;
        //...
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use **PropertyChangedCallback** while creating the dependency property. If you want it to be executed ONLY ONCE and then do not allow the user to change it, you can try manipulating it in the PropertyChangedCallback.

```
    public bool NeedToDrawRect
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(NeedToDrawRectProperty); }
        set
        {
            SetValue(NeedToDrawRectProperty, value);
        }
    }


    public static readonly DependencyProperty NeedToDrawRectProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("NeedToDrawRect",
            typeof(bool),
            typeof(PanZoomImage),
            new PropertyMetadata(false, OnNeedToDrawRectChanged ));

    private static void OnNeedToDrawRectChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var control = d as PanZoomImage;
        if (control!=null && (bool)e.NewValue == false && (bool)e.OldValue == true)
        {
            control.NeedToDrawRect = true; // user won't be able to set it to false again.
        }
    }
```

This should work. If you are using a checkbox to perform the operation, Bind the **IsReadOnly** property of the checkbox to the property **NeedToDrawRect** so that once the user sets it to true, the user won't be able to change it again. You might need an **InverseBooleanConverter** to do this.

Comment: Besides that it doesn't answer the question, this makes no sense at all. Don't change or reset a dependency property value in its PropertyChangedCallback. Instead, use a CoerceValueCallback.

Comment: CoerceValueCallback is not available everywhere for e.g. UWP. Plus keeping a value to keep track if the value is changed won't also work because the Callback will always trigger as and when the user changes the value from UI.

Comment: The question is not about UWP. And it doesn't ask for how to force a property to be always true after being set once.

Comment: There are several ways to solve the problem. One solution is Implement a PropertyChanged and call the RaisePropertyChanged from the property. Update the value in the Setter ONLY WHEN the current value is false and then raise property changed. But as user mentioned DependencyProperty this is not the case.


And I have already suggested to disable the UI element if the value is already changed.

Would be helpful if you can suggest a working solution in your way that changes the value only once.

Comment: There is no need to "suggest a working solution". The question already has an accepted answer. There's nothing more to say than that.